# Append two vars from xml to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I have two vars from xml file in my js, how can i append both of them in my #list ul as li elements? I mean, each li element must include title and url from script.

```js
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "#",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function (xml) {
                    $(xml).find('HotelExportElionDto').each(function (hotelList) {
                        $(this).find("Title").each(function () {
                            var title = $(this).text();
                        });
                        $(this).find("SeoUrl").each(function () {
                            var url = $(this).text();
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.append()` but you have to change your code little bit:

```
$(xml).find('HotelExportElionDto').each(function(hotelList) {
  var li="";
  var title = $(this).find("Title").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get();
  $(this).find("SeoUrl").each(function(i) {
    li += "<li>" + title[i] +"<-:title::|::url:->"+ $(this).text() + "</li>";
  });
});

$('#list').append(li);
```

Comment: @VladimirHumeniuk glad to help you. keep visiting.